# How to read uniform_int_distribution's probability mass function?

Tags: c++, math

**uniform_int_distribution** uses the following
**probability mass function**:

```
P(i|a,b) = 1/(b-a+1), a <= i <= b
```

How does one *read* the LHS of the equation,ie: `P(i|a,b)` ?

Comment: This might be better suited on [Math.SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Actually, I had posted it [there](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2670772/probability-mass-function-notation), but there was no convincing answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This means "P (the chance) of outcome i, depending on parameters a and b, is (1/b-a+1) when i is in the range a to b, and zero outside that range".

It's uniform because all values of i between a and b are equally likely.

Answer (score 0):

This means how far I assume that
P is probability of  occurrence of i , in between interval a and b.
i couldnot go the range below a or higher than b